# error SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE only in new GCM client sample

Tags: android, exception, google-cloud-messaging, service-not-available

I downloaded and implemented the **new** GCM client sample that uses Class `GoogleCloudMessaging` from library `google-play-services.jar`. I get error `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`. I know that the jar file is the last version. I studied every posts about error `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` but I could not solve it.

Then I tested the **old** GCM client sample that uses `gcm.jar`. I could register my device successfully and got registration ID. Because my package name for these two applications was same I could use that registration ID in the **new** sample and the application worked correctly and got messages successfully.

So now I know that the error in **new** GCM client sample is not about my Wi-Fi or firewall or…

Now I want to know what the real problem is. My manifests in two projects are same and I have all needed permissions in both manifests.

What should I do now? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new GCM API has [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=57699&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=57699#makechanges) which is still not resolved.

However, the new GCM works on devices with API level 17 and higher. So you can continue using the depreciated API till the issue gets resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will wait for the bug get solved.